# Two entries of Fedora 38 in GRUB menu

Tags: grub, fedora-38

I recently dual boot Windows 10 and Fedora 38 update the system and now it's showing two entries. How do I delete one of entries?

- Fedora Linux (6.3.5-200 .fc38.x86_64) 38 (Workstation Edition)
- Fedora Linux (6.2.9-200 .fc38.x86_64) 38 (Workstation Edition)

[image: GRUB menu]

Comment: can you explain why this problem exists

Comment: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Fedora keeps last 3 kernels installed, in case something goes wrong and you need to revert, and the GRUB menu doesn't place them under any sort of "Advanced options" menu, like it's done in some other distros. It instead automatically adds them to the root menu.

To get rid of them, you'd need to remove appriopriate `.conf` configs in `/boot/loader/entries`, based on the versions of unneeded kernels. New configs will appear after upgrading though.

Alternatively, you can also remove older kernels, but that's not recommended because you lose safety and could accidentally remove something you shouldn't. They'll also come back whenever you upgrade, so no difference in that regard.

Comment: thanks for the explanation